# C# ERROR: Gridview Row count

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to display the count of grid view

can anyone tell me what i did wrong in this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    gridview1.DataSource = Session["dsource"];
    gridview1.DataBind();
    Response.Write(gridview1.Rows.Count.ToString);

}
```

the error appears in the response.write line

Comment: Please add the exact error/exception message text to a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can delete ToString. 'gridview1.Rows.Count' will be automaticly converted to string.

If you want to leave ToString you need () in the end, ToString(). It's a method.

Best regards, Dima.

Answer (score 4):

ToString is a method, not a property.

```
Response.Write(gridview1.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

Of course, you could always use the version that will call ToString() for you.

```
Response.Write(gridview1.Rows.Count);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need extra `()`:

```
   Response.Write(gridview1.Rows.Count.ToString());
```